# Access data from ViewData["Brand"] in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller i have a list of items. that i stored in `ViewData["Brand"]`.

In my view those data is blinded to dropdownlist.

the list is coming in view.

Now i want to pass the selected item value to model when ever i select the dropdownlist in view.

How to access the items in `ViewData["Brand"]`.

Here is my code.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("BrandName", ViewData["BrandName"] as SelectList, "--Select--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the items to list and stored in ViewData[BrandName]

Controller Code:

```
        IList<BrandInfo> brand = new List<BrandInfo>();
        int CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["CategoryId"]);
        productInstance.CategoryId = CategoryId;
        brand = get****(CategoryId);
        IList<SelectListItem> BrandNameList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in brand)
        {
            SelectListItem sli = new SelectListItem();
            sli.Text = item._name;
            sli.Value = Convert.ToString(item._brandId);
            if (sli.Value == BrandId.ToString())
            {
                sli.Selected = true;
            }
            BrandNameList.Add(sli);
        }
        ViewData["BrandName"] = BrandNameList;
```

MOdel:

```
public string BrandName { get; set; }
```

View Code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BrandName", ViewData["BrandName"] as SelectList, "-- Select By Brands --")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to send back a list of brands i.e. _brands will be your list of brands populated from your db or elsewhere.

```
var brandId = "1";
var brands = _brands.Select(b => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = b.Id.ToString(),
                Text = b.Name,
                Selected = brandId.Equals(b.Id.ToString())

            });

ViewData["BrandId"] = = "1";
ViewData["Brands"] = brands;
```

The important part in the above is:

```
Selected = brandId.Equals(b.Id.ToString());
```

This will do the pre-selecting of the list.

Then the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("BrandId", ViewData["Brands"] as SelectList, "--Select--", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" });
```